# No HDMI output on Debian 8 laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, hdmi, external-display

WHAT DOESN'T WORK:

I'm running Debian 8 on a Dell M4800 laptop and I'm unable to get it to talk to a new external monitor via either HDMI or DisplayPort.

The Debian 8 (Mate) Live USB also does not recognize the external monitor with the HDMI connection.

WHAT WORKS:

VGA works well with the same setup (Debian 8, Mate or Openbox).  In all cases the laptop's own display works just fine.

I know the HDMI and DisplayPort cables and ports are okay because the Ubuntu 14.04.1 Desktop Edition Live USB recognizes the external monitor with either of those (though both are very slightly flaky: (a) the mouse/trackpad sometimes leaves a trail on the external display which goes away if I click somewhere, and (b) there's a thin vertical line on the left edge of the external display to the left of the Unity Launcher).

HARDWARE INFO AND DIAGNOSTICS:

I'm trying to do this with integrated Intel HD 4600 but the live USBs both use the discrete GPU (Nvidia Quadro K1100) with the nouveau driver.

I've run `udevadm monitor` to see if the monitor is at least recognized, and it's recognized with the VGA connection but not with the HDMI connection.

Can someone please tell me how to get the HDMI connection working with Debian 8?  I don't even know where to begin looking, so any advice would help.  It looks to me like a kernel issue but in that case it's not clear why Ubuntu recognizes it and Debian does not, since they're both running 3.16 kernels.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Generally speaking, signatures at the end of posts are discouraged here, since your username appears at the bottom of the post automatically.